# Nested IF formula in Excel

Tags: excel-2007, excel-formula

I am trying to write a nested IF statement in excel and struggling to get it right.

My formula is looking for a value "NA" in specific cells of my row and if the condition is TRUE, then it should subtract a specific number in the division and if the condition is not TRUE then it should not subtract the number from the division .

for example if J10="NA" is true then (CC10/CC4-K4 )% otherwise it should be (CC10/CC4)%.Likewise if J10="NA" is false and  R10="NA" is TRUE then my division part should be (CC10/CC4-S4 )% and should not include the cell 'K4'. I hope I was able to make it clear??

Below is my formula:

=IF(OR(J10="NA", R10="NA", Z10="NA"),(CC10/($CC$4-K4-S4-AA4)%), CC10/CC4%)

Comment: You only care about J, R & Z = "NA"?? ALSO, what if J10 = "NA" AND R10 = "NA"? Please elaborate a little more about exactly what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
=CC10/($CC$4-(J10="NA")*$K$4-(R10="NA")*$S$4-(Z10="NA")*$AA$4)%
```

Comment: Thx Tigeravatar. This is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated :)